# ajax call and $.watch in Angular

Tags: json, ajax, angularjs

I need to generate a select menu when a button is clicked. I am making an ajax call to get json data from external file, upon button click. which In turn should update the select with data from json. with the code below the select gets updated only after the button is clicked twice. I am watching the jsonData but its not working as expected.

HTML:

```
 <div ng-controller="MainViewCtrl">
   <button ng-click="getDeployedResources()"> Load Resources </button>
   <select ng-model="selectedOption.name" ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in jsonData"></select>
 </div>
```

json from dropdown.json:

```
{
    "DeployedResources": {
        "-env": "dev13",
        "ResourceList": {
            "-exportTime": 1444999007878,
            "Resource": [{
                    "name": "default",
                    "type": "project"
              },
                {
                    "name": "System",
                    "type": "project"
               },
                {
                    "name": "StratusCommonServices",
                    "type": "project"
              }]
           }
       }
}
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('JSONedit', ['ui.sortable'])

.controller('MainViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter','$compile',   function ($scope, $http, $filter, $compile) {
$scope.jsonData = {};

$scope.getDeployedResources = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json/dropdown.json',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        $scope.jsonData = data.DeployedResources.ResourceList.Resource;
        $scope.selectedOption = angular.copy($scope.jsonData[0]);
    });
}


$scope.$watch('jsonData', function (json) {
    $scope.jsonString = $filter('json')(json);
}, true);
$scope.$watch('jsonString', function (json) {
    try {
        $scope.jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
        $scope.wellFormed = true;
    } catch (e) {
        $scope.wellFormed = false;
    }
}, true);

}])
```

Comment: why don't you use $http service from angular instead ? If you do it, the update will hapen in angularjs context, while it won't do as you got it now. You need to call $apply() with your current code.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo... using http$ solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct life-cycle of a simple AngularJS Component!
Don't use jQuery for doing something that angular does better!

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .service('DataService', function($q, $http) {
    var self = this;

    var mock = {
      id: 1,
      "DeployedResources": {
        "-env": "dev13",
        "ResourceList": {
          "-exportTime": 1444999007878,
          "Resource": [{
            "name": "default",
            "type": "project"
          }, {
            "name": "System",
            "type": "project"
          }, {
            "name": "StratusCommonServices",
            "type": "project"
          }]
        }
      }
    };

    self.load = function() {
      console.log('loading data', mock.id);
      for (var i = 0, len = mock.DeployedResources.ResourceList.Resource.length; i < len; i++) {
        mock.DeployedResources.ResourceList.Resource[i].name += mock.id;
      }

      mock.id += 1;
      return $q.when(mock);

      return $http
        .get('/api/data/')
        .then(function(result) {
          return result.data;
        });
    }
  })
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {
    var vm = $scope;
    
    vm.select = {
      current: null,
      items: []
    };

    vm.loadData = function(event) {
      console.count('load data');

      return DataService
        .load()
        .then(function(data) {
          vm.current = data.id;
          return data.DeployedResources.ResourceList.Resource;
        })
        .then(function(items) {
          vm.select.items = items;
          vm.select.current = vm.select.items[0];
        })
    };

    vm.loadData();
  });
```

```css
.select-wrapper {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  background: yellow;
}
.select-wrapper select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<article ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <button type="button" ng-click="loadData($event);">LoadNew</button>
    <div class="select-wrapper">
      <select ng-model="select.current" ng-options="item as item.name for item in select.items"></select>
    </div>
    <div ng-bind="select.items | json"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```